# Compare a date column to today's date in dax im not getting the correct output as required

Tags: dax, sql-date-functions

I have column datetimesent through which I will get to know that the schedule is gone for today, so I'm trying to write if else query where if datetimesent is today's date then schedule running else false.

My existing column is is in date format I need to compare it with inbuilt today/now function, but they are in datetime format, I'm not getting the output correct

Answer (score 0):

You can use DATE() function to build date from your timestamp
for example:

```
DATE(YEAR([YourTimestampColumn]),MONTH([YourTimestampColumn]),DAY([YourTimestampColumn]))
```